# jQuery: Adding <span></span> to text inside a <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

firstly here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/0o8fo705/)

I want to add a `<span class="Text"></span>` to text ''RSS' inside an `<li>`.

HTML Code:

```
    <ul>
    <li class="hasToolTip"> RSS Feeds</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: to Only RSS or whole RSS feed ??

Comment: @Rohit Arora: Only RSS

Comment: Do you want <li class='hasToolTip'><span>RSS Feeds</span></li> or <li class='hasToolTip'><span>RSS</span> Feeds</li> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the li that contains text RSS. and then use `.html()` call back function to replace the each occurrence of RSS with span wrapped around it:

```
$("li.hasToolTip:contains('RSS')").html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/(RSS)/g, '<span class="Text">RSS</span>');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4srzn76b/)**

Comment: Thank you @Milind Anantwar. I will select this as answer.